# Stein Factorisations and Relative Normalisations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

A universally closed and quasi-separated morphism $f:X\to S$ admits a [factorisation](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03GY), as $\pi\circ f'$, where $\pi:\underline{\mathbf{Spec}}_S(f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X)\to S$ is an integral morphism, and $f':X\to \underline{\mathbf{Spec}}_S(f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a universally closed, quasi-compact, quasi-separated, and surjective morphism.

Item (5) in [Tag 03GY](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03GY) at the Stacks Project asserts that $\pi$ is the normalisation of $S$ in $X$. However, the [normalisation](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035H) of $S$ in $X$ is defined to be the relative spectrum of the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_S$in $f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$ over $S$.

> Is $f^\#:\mathcal{O}_S \to f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$ integeral, giving that $f$ ia universally closed and quasi-separated, or is item (5) wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universally closed morphisms are quasi-compact, by Tag [04XU](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XU). Since $f$ is universally closed and quasi-separated, $f^\#:\mathcal{O}_S\to f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$ is integral, by Tag [03GQ](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03GQ).